# Not to talk or to not talk

Tags: british-english

Which one is more accurate to be used in sentence. I could see many times people use "I tried not to talk" is that correct use of sentence?

Comment: Well, it's a weird sentence because it's a double negative. I don't know when I would ever say, "I will **never** allow you **not** to talk with him." It's just a strange sentence.

Comment: If, however, you just want to know where to put the **not**, then it's more formal to say "not to talk"; however, there is nothing wrong with "to not talk". Some people say it's splitting an infinitive, but there is no hard-and-fast rule in English about splitting infinitives. That's just merely a made-up rule that some pedant took from Latin probably during the Enlightenment and people have tried to adhere to it ever since despite its not being an official rule in English.

Comment: Hi sir ,  I have changed the sentence

Comment: I challenge your original assertion that "many times people use _I will never allow you not to talk with him_". I just Googled `"I will never allow you not to talk with"` and only found 1 hit  – your question here on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases "**to not talk**" isn't the best English (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73224/should-we-use-not-to-or-to-not) for a more detailed explanation) - better use "**not to talk**" to be more clear or more emphatic.

- You are not to talk to him ever!

However sentences like the following can work and won't be a mistake.

- When it started getting darker I decided to go home, to not stay for the night.

Comment: I have corrected the example sentence which I have asked above. Thanks

Comment: I absolutely agree--especially with your exception "to not stay for the night."

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no rule that says that one cannot split infinitives as you are doing with "to not talk".  Despite its not being a rule, it is still better to say "not to talk" because many people stickle about this pseudo rule.

> "You are **to not talk** to him." (Acceptable English)
>
> "You are **not to talk** to him." (Better English)

Comment: Why did you use " are " in this sentence?

Comment: Because "are" is the second person singular/plural conjugation of "to be" and we're both using the "to be" verb here. "You are + infinitive" is basically a command such as, "You **shall** (not) talk to him!"

Comment: Yes. "He is **to go** to school tomorrow" is basically a command: "He **shall** go to school tomorrow. "I am **to be** in the play that they are going to perform" is basically a simple future prediction: "I **shall** be in the play."

Comment: " He has to go to school tomorrow " this is normal sentence but " he is to" it's fist time I'm seeing this kind of usage. However , I want to know more about this format. Would you please provide me a link to know more about it.

Comment: http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the remainder of this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70891/discussion-on-answer-by-nick-not-to-talk-or-to-not-talk).